# Disable default trace log messages from Web App in Application insights

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I have created a Web App in Azure and a Web API in .Net core framework following the instructions in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet).
Now in my Web App , Application Insights is enabled.
In WebAPI has some similar code for logging.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup()
    {
    } 
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ConsoleLogger>();
        logger.LogInformation("Executing Configure()");
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ILogger _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Executing Home/Index")
        return View();
    } 
}
```

By default, it is printing some trace logs something like similar in Application Insights.

```
2019-01-02T07:22:49 Executing Home/Index
2019-01-02T07:22:49 Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
2019-01-02T07:22:50 Executed action [SomeActionName] (APIName) in 6487.7982ms
2019-01-02T07:22:50 Request finished in 6917.8019ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Now my requirement is it should not print all the default logs in Application Insights. It has to print only those with  `_logger.LogInformation`. How and where do I disable this feature?

Comment: Where are these logs, in Azure or your VS?

Comment: @TaoZhou It is in Azure.

Comment: You can use ITelemetryProcessor to filter out the unnecessary trace messages.

Comment: @IvanYang it would be kind of you, if you could show me an example

Comment: Yes, just for a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ITelemetryProcessor to filter out the unwanted messages(including the Trace).

1.You can test your project locally with app insights, and then use **Application insights search** to check the unwanted trace messages, check it's **CategoryName**(or others property which can specify it), like screenshot below:

[image]

2.Create a custom class which implements the ITelemetryProcessor. Here I use the CategoryName to filter out the unwanted trace messages, you can adjust the code yourself:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace WebApplication1netcore4
{
    public class MyTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
    {
        private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

        public MyTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
        {
            this.Next = next;
        }

        public void Process(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {

            TraceTelemetry trace = telemetry as TraceTelemetry;

            if (trace != null && trace.Context.Properties.Keys.Contains("CategoryName"))
            {
                //Here I just filter out 2 kinds of trace messages, you can adjust your code as per your need.
                if (trace.Context.Properties["CategoryName"] == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost" || trace.Context.Properties["CategoryName"] == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker")
                {
                    //return means abandon this trace message which has the specified CategoryName
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (trace == null)
            {
                this.Next.Process(telemetry);

            }

            if (trace != null)
            {
                this.Next.Process(trace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3.In Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices() method, add the following code:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<MyTelemetryProcessor>();
```

4.After test, you can see the unwanted trace messages are filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to disable certain types of log messages is through the appsettings.json:

```
"Logging": {
 "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Trace",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost": "None",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker": "None",
 }
},
```

This disables the same telemetry as @Ivan Young's answer but allows you to change the settings without code changes.

Comment: It doesn't work for me... I still see all internal logs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you have enabled Ilogger integration with application insights, but the currently supported way is described here.
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Logging

The second parameter to the extension method controls which messages gets picked up by application insights.
loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Warning);

This should limit logs Warning or above to be sent to application insights. You can ofcourse use a ITelemetryprocessor to filter the logs, but thats more expensive as logs are already collected but later dropped, wasting computation cycles/memory.