# How to temporary stop logging RequestTrackingTelemetryModule in Application Insights for ASP.NET MVC(.NET Full)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

How can we stop logging specific module such as RequestTrackingTelemetryModule in ASP.NET MVC (.NET Full, not .NET Core)

I have tried to remove

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
```

in **ApplicationInsights.config** but it throws me a strange exception

I am using Azure Web App for both staging and live environments. So I just want to stop logging request information on live environment since it cost too much.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You just want to not log any request telemetry?

Comment: @IvanYang For now, yes

Comment: @IvanYang however if I can do it apart, it's still okay

Comment: it's possible to do it by using [ITelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c).

Comment: You can take a look at this [thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002813/disable-default-trace-log-messages-from-web-app-in-application-insights) I answered before, just make some changes(it's for .net core, you should make some changes).

Comment: Please refer to my answer below, and let me if any questions.

Comment: @IvanYang thanks for quick help. I'm gonna add your code and tell you result soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ITelemetryProcessor, and following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c).

Add a custom class which implements ITelemetryProcessor:

```
public class MyTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    public MyTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {

        RequestTelemetry request = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;

        if (request != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (request == null)
        {
            this.Next.Process(telemetry);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the ApplicationInsights.config, add this:

```
<TelemetryProcessors>
    <Add Type="WebApplicationMVC.MyTelemetryProcessor, WebApplicationMVC">
      <!-- Set public property -->     
    </Add>
  </TelemetryProcessors>
```

the screenshot:

[image]

It did filter out all the requests from app insights data, test result as below:

[image]